# Sessions and LDAP

Tags: php, session, ldap

I have a webpage. The authentication to the webpage is handled by a ldap server I have set up. Now I wan`t to implement sessions, so that when a user is inactive for a period of time (in the case below, 10 seconds), the session will end and the user will unbind from the ldap server. I found this excerpt of code:

```
<?php
    session_cache_expire(20);

    session_start(); 
    $inactive = 10;
    if(isset($_SESSION['start'])) {
        $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['start'];
        if($session_life > $inactive){
            header("Location: endSession.php"); 

        }
    }
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
?>
```

It is not working. If I refresh the page it redirects me to my 'endSession.php' page, even if I`m active.

Comment: did you mean 10 minutes?

Comment: No. 10 seconds. It`s just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function check_auth_ldap () {

  $sessionTimeoutSecs = 10;
  $ldapServer = '11.22.33.44';
  $ldapPort = 389;

  if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

  if (!empty($_SESSION['lastactivity']) && $_SESSION['lastactivity'] > time() - $sessionTimeoutSecs && !isset($_GET['logout'])) {

    // Session is already authenticated
    $ds = ldap_connect($ldapServer, $ldapPort);
    if (ldap_bind($ds, $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'])) {
      $_SESSION['lastactivity'] = time();
      return $ds;
    } else {
      unset($_SESSION['lastactivity'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']);
      header("Location: endSession.php");
      exit;
    }

  } else if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {

    // Handle login requests
    $ds = ldap_connect($ldapServer, $ldapPort);
    if (ldap_bind($ds, $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
      // Successful auth
      $_SESSION['lastactivity'] = time();
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
      $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
      return $ds;
    } else {
      // Auth failed
      header("Location: endSession.php");
      exit;
    }

  } else {

    // Session has expired or a logout was requested
    unset($_SESSION['lastactivity'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']);
    header("Location: endSession.php");
    exit;

  }

}
```

Just call the above function at the top of every protected page. This will handle all the authentication processes. It will return the LDAP connection resource if the user is authenticated, and redirect them to `endSession.php` if they are not.

Just place this line at the top of each page:

```
$ds = check_auth_ldap();
```

...and the function will do all the legwork for you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to explain that in the question: The POST variables come from the login form - so your login form looks like `<form action="yourscript.php" method="post"><input type="text" name="username" /><input type="password" name="password" /></form>`. You can logout by passing a GET parameter of `logout` - it doesn't matter what the value is, just that the key is set

Answer (score 2):

There is often a need for a bind based on the uid. I've modified the function a little to achieve this. cn for bind comes from a search operation based on uid for username. Hope this could help someone.

```
function check_auth_ldap () {

  if (!($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'])) {

    header("Location: login.php?failure=6");

  }

  $sessionTimeoutSecs = 10;
  $ldapServer = localhost;
  $ldapBaseDN = ou=users,ou=subtree,dc=domain,dc=tld;
  $ldapPort = 389;
  $ldapFilter = "(&(objectClass=*)(uid=".$_POST['username']."))";
  $ldapAttributes = array("cn");

  if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

  if (!empty($_SESSION['lastactivity']) && $_SESSION['lastactivity'] > time() - $sessionTimeoutSecs && !isset($_GET['logout'])) {

    // Session is already authenticated
    $ds = ldap_connect($ldapServer, $ldapPort);
    $sr = ldap_search($ds,$ldapBaseDN,$ldapFilter,$ldapAttributes);
    $result = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

    if ($result) {
        $binddn = $result[0]['dn'];
    } else {
        header("Location: login.php?failure=1");
    }

    ldap_close ($ds);

    $ds = ldap_connect($ldapServer, $ldapPort);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    if (ldap_bind($ds, $binddn, $_SESSION['password'])) {
      $_SESSION['lastactivity'] = time();
      return $ds;
    } else {
      unset($_SESSION['lastactivity'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']);
      header("Location: login.php?failure=2");
      exit;
    }

  } else if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {

    // Handle login requests
    $ds = ldap_connect($ldapServer, $ldapPort);
    $sr = ldap_search($ds,$ldapBaseDN,$ldapFilter,$ldapAttributes);
    $result = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

    if ($result) {
        $binddn = $result[0]['dn'];
    } else {
        header("Location: login.php?failure=3");
    }
    ldap_close ($ds);

    $ds = ldap_connect($ldapServer, $ldapPort);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    if (ldap_bind($ds, $binddn, $_POST['password'])) {
      // Successful auth
      $_SESSION['lastactivity'] = time();
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
      $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
      return $ds;
    } else {
      // Auth failed
      header("Location: login.php?failure=4");
      exit;
    }

  } else {

    // Session has expired or a logout was requested
    unset($_SESSION['lastactivity'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']);
    header("Location: login.php?failure=5");
    exit;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just written (and tested) this:

**test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['start']))
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();

if(time() - $_SESSION['start'] > 10)
    echo 'Logged out';
else 
    echo 'Logged in';

?>
```

If you go to `test.php?start` in your browser, it will say "Logged in", then go to `test.php` in your browser and any time after 10 seconds, it will echo "Logged out", any time under 10 seconds it will say "Logged in"